# How to schedule a cron job in windows to execute a query or stored procedure in oracle database at specific interval?

Tags: database, oracle, cron

I hava a database where I want to perform query on one table, and push its output to another table and this need to be done at specific time interval.I want to do this using cron in windows.I am using oracle database.
Please let me know the steps and files need to be created for the same.

Comment: You can just use the DBMS_SCHEDULER package in oracle.  FYI, SO is not a tutorial site.  Please see [ask]

Comment: But what if I wanna do it via Cron in Windows, any link for that

Comment: Then use google

Comment: I didn't get , that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Cron does not exist in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you're scheduling a job in Oracle then you almost certainly want to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.  It is safer, more powerful, and more reliable than default operating system schedulers.  It's also portable, and the same job will work no matter what platform Oracle is running on.

If someone asked you to "create a cron job on Windows", they probably used the word "cron" in a generic sense to mean some sort of scheduling system.  Windows does not have cron by default.  I'm sure there's a way to install it, but why add non-standard, less powerful software?

```
--Create initial objects:
create table test1(a number);
insert into test1 values(1);
create table test2(a number);

--Create the job:
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name => 'daily_table_copy',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action =>
        q'[
            begin
                insert into test2
                select * from test1;

                commit;
            end;
        ]',
        repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;byhour=4;byminute=0;',
        start_date => systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern'
    );
end;
/

--Monitor the job:
select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'DAILY_TABLE_COPY';
select * from dba_scheduler_running_jobs where job_name = 'DAILY_TABLE_COPY';
```

Comment: Thanks for above solution. But can I do the same using quartz and timer in java?

Comment: @Aviii04 Yes but that would significantly complicate this task.  If your data is already in Oracle, then the above code creates no new dependencies.  Java and Quartz are fine products, but unless you already have them installed and ready to go, it would be a lot of effort to install and maintain them for such a trivial task.